# c# find if a variable is defined in a model

Tags: c#, mvvm

I'm currently developing a MVVM application and I have been stuck trying to figure a way out of this.
So I have a model built as such:

```
public class Variables
{
    /* Elementary variables */
    public static readonly UInt16 Var1 = 1;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var2 = 2;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var3 = 3;
}
```

I want in a viewModel to check if a string I have from user input which should match either Var1, Var2 or Var3 (name of the variable not its value) actually does.

Something like
`if (UserInput.Name in VariablesName){ }`

Where variablesName would be the list of the Variables of Variables
for instanace it would be true if the user had input "Var1"

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have these three variables, I recommend to add a collection that contains the variable names:

```
public class Variables
{
    /* Elementary variables */
    public static readonly UInt16 Var1 = 1;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var2 = 2;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var3 = 3;
    public static IEnumerable<string> VariableNames { get; } = new string[] { nameof(Var1), nameof(Var2), nameof(Var3) };
}
```

However, if you often add or remove variables, this might not be a good solution, because you have to remember each time to also add or remove an item from the collection. In that case, you can use reflection:

```
public class Variables
{
    /* Elementary variables */
    public static readonly UInt16 Var1 = 1;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var2 = 2;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var3 = 3;
    public static IEnumerable<string> VariableNames
    {
       get
       {
          return typeof(Variables).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Select(x => x.Name);
       }
    }
}
```

You should be aware, that reflection is quite slow. If you need high performance, this is not a good solution. You can gain a bit of performance if you execute the reflection code just once, not at every call of the getter of the property:

```
public class Variables
{
    /* Elementary variables */
    public static readonly UInt16 Var1 = 1;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var2 = 2;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var3 = 3;
    public static IEnumerable<string> VariableNames { get; } = typeof(Variables).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();
}
```

Online-demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mWc6AP

Comment: I would make call to reflection only once, at initialization of a class. So we don't redo reflection operation again and again, just once.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new ViewModel().CheckVariable("Var1");
        new ViewModel().CheckVariable("Var4");
    }
}

public class Variables
{
    /* Elementary variables */
    public static readonly UInt16 Var1 = 1;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var2 = 2;
    public static readonly UInt16 Var3 = 3;
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public void CheckVariable(string userInput)
    {
        // Get all static fields of the Variables class
        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Variables).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

        // Convert the fields array to a list of their names
        var fieldNames = new List<string>();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            fieldNames.Add(field.Name);
        }

        // Check if the userInput matches any of the field names
        if (fieldNames.Contains(userInput))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{userInput} is a valid variable name.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{userInput} is not a valid variable name.");
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewModel.CheckVariable` method gets all the static fields of the Variables class using `typeof(Variables).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)`. It then converts this array of FieldInfo objects to a list of strings, containing the names of the fields.